# How to showing file icon in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, attachment

I want to show an icon in my project for a file that I uploaded using `paperclip`.
Only when a file extension is `.pdf`, then the icon must show a `pdf` icon and so for another file extension, same goes on..

this is my code

```
  <% @recent_files.each do |file| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= image_tag file.resume(:thumb), :width => "100" if file.resume %></td>
      <td><%#= @student.name%></td>
      <td><%= file.resume_file_name%><br/>
          <%= file.resume_updated_at%></td>
    </tr>
  <%end%>
```

Could anyone help me?

Advance Thanks

Comment: Please show your initial efforts.

Comment: almost forget a code :) 
need advice

Answer (score 0):

1. You should prepare icons for pdf and file types you would refer, put them into a folder like `'your_project/public/images/icons'`
2. Append a config hash in model File.rb:

   FileIcon = {

   :pdf => '/images/icons/pdf.png',

   :doc => '/images/icons/doc.png'

   #... and other any file types, all like this

   }
3. Page code like this:

   `<%= image_tag File::FileIcon[file.resume(:thumb).scan(/\.(\w+)\?\d*$/)[0].try(:to_sym)], :width => "100" if file.resume %>`

Comment: i got an errors "undefined method `to_sym' for ["docx"]:Array"

Comment: try this: <%= image_tag File::FileIcon[file.resume(:thumb).scan(/\.(\w+)\?\d*$/)[0][0].try(:to_sym)], :width => "100" if file.resume %> . And if you use docx file, dont forget to add :docx => '/images/icons/docx.png' to File::FileIcon, and put the file in the folder

Comment: or like this: File::FileIcon[file.resume(:thumb).match(/\.(\w+)\?\d*$/)[1].try(:to_sym)], anyway, you just need to extract the expanded-name and map the image path for it.